# p5js - touchStarted event on specific object

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I want to use `p5js` to create game then wrap it with `Cordova`. I want to create a spaceship that when I click on it, it will shoot a bullet. Below is my code:

```
function setup() {
  canvas = createCanvas(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
  spr = createSprite(width/2, height-50,
    40, 40);
  spr.shapeColor = color(255);

    spr.onMousePressed = function() {
    console.log("mouse press");
    var bullet = createSprite(spr.position.x, spr.position.y - 50, 10, 40);
    bullets.push(bullet);
  }

}
```

I test it with `Google Chrome` and it works with mouse. However if I change it mobile development mode, it doesn't work anymore. I tried

```
spr.touchStarted = function() {
    console.log("mouse press");
    var bullet = createSprite(spr.position.x, spr.position.y - 50, 10, 40);
    bullets.push(bullet);   }
```

I wonder if There is a way for me to do that.

Comment: Can you please be more specific than saying it doesn't work anymore? What exactly does that code do instead?

Comment: In other words, can you please post a [mcve] that we can actually run?